# Raspberry Pi: Wirelessly controlling GPIO pins with CGI

Tags: python, html, linux, cgi, raspberry-pi

I'm attempting to control a servo with my RPI's GPIO pins. I can successfully run the script from my pi directly to get the servo to work. I want to be able to do this from an HTML page running on an apache server. I'm using CGI scripts to do this but am having no luck. Located in /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
I have this python script to activate the servo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(7, GPIO.OUT)

try:
        while True:
                GPIO.output(7, 1)
                time.sleep(.0005)
                GPIO.output(7,0)

                time.sleep(.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Then in my HTML page I have it set up like this script run on button click...

```
document.location="cgi-bin/on.py";
```

But when i click the button i get no results. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this belongs in the Raspberry Pi Forums. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Someone already did such thing: https://code.google.com/p/webiopi/

Comment: when the script gets called via the cgi, is it being run with root permissions? I think that gpio needs root to run correctly.